# Xming - cannot enter any text

Tags: windows, x11, xming

Whenever I try to enter something in a input place holder I get the below error:

```
init_screen_visuals:1336: init_screen_visuals
(--) 3 mouse buttons found
(--) Setting autorepeat to delay=500, rate=31
(--) winConfigKeyboard - Layout: "00000409" (00000409) 
(--) Using preset keyboard for "English (USA)" (409), type "7"
Could not init font path element C:\Program Files (x86)\Xming/fonts/misc/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element C:\Program Files (x86)\Xming/fonts/TTF/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element C:\Program Files (x86)\Xming/fonts/Type1/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element C:\Program Files (x86)\Xming/fonts/75dpi/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element C:\Program Files (x86)\Xming/fonts/100dpi/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element C:\Program Files\Xming\fonts\dejavu, removing from list!
Could not init font path element C:\Program Files\Xming\fonts\cyrillic, removing from list!
Could not init font path element C:\WINDOWS\Fonts, removing from list!
winInitMultiWindowWM - pthread_mutex_lock () returned.

winClipboardFlushXEvents - SelectionNotify - XConvertSelection () failed for CompoundText, aborting: 1
```

How can I fix this? It is blocking my work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to install the fonts you will find here:

http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/

Comment: I tried that - but it did not work the issue persists  - is there any alternative to xming, it is giving me really hard times

Comment: By the way, if you want to use xming, you should check some configurations. Please read the additional notes in this webpage: http://kb.kaminskiengineering.com/node/41

Comment: MobaXterm from http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net is the best one. It is much easier to use than Xming.

Comment: Great! Nice talking to you :)

Comment: Just that someone else with this problem knows => for me installing the fonts did solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

Download Xming font separately-
http://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/files/Xming-fonts/

select all options 75dpi,100dpi etc..
And you are done!!!